# Numpy / Chebyshev Module: get value

Tags: python, numpy

I have built a Chebyshev polynomial based on given values.

```
x = [1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008]
y = [121.093,121.092,121.091,121.090,121.090,121.089,121.084,121.079,121.081]
from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev as T
p = T.fit(x, y, 2)
xx, yy = p.linspace(n=10)
plt.plot(xx, yy)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Now I need to get "Y" value of the Chebyshev polynomial for a given "X".

```
np.polynomial.chebyshev.chebval(1, p.coef)
```

> 121.0791090909091

But the first "Y" in my data is "**121.093**". OK let's try "1000":

```
np.polynomial.chebyshev.chebval(1000, p.coef)
```

> -2898.698090887721

**QUESTION**

> How to get "Y" value when "X" = 1000? I expect to get "**121.093**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the keyword window in your call to Chebyshev.fit(). Have a look at the snippet below.

```
import numpy.polynomial.chebyshev as cheb
x = [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008]
y = [121.093, 121.092, 121.091, 121.090, 121.090, 121.089, 121.084, 121.079,
     121.081]
p = cheb.Chebyshev.fit(x, y, 2, window=[1000, 1008])
print(cheb.chebval(1000, p.coef))
# 121.09270909090891
```